# Turning a promise in a for loop into an array of values

Tags: javascript, for-loop, recursion, async-await, promise

I have the following code:

```
  newIds = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < combinedIds.length; i++) {
    thisId = combinedIds[i];
    **console.log(checkForAssoc(thisId))**;
  }
  async function checkForAssoc(docId) {
    check = newIds.includes(docId);
    if (check) {
      return;
    } else {
      newIds.push(docId);
    }
    docToCheck = await adminModel.letterModel.findById(docId);
    if (docToCheck.assocLetters.length > 0) {
      newDocToCheckArry = docToCheck.assocLetters;
      for (let n = 0; n < newDocToCheckArry.length; n++) {
        checkForAssoc(newDocToCheckArry[n]);
      }
    }
    return await newIds;
  }
```

I am trying to loop over an array `combinedIds` (which contains a number of mongoDB ids) and based on that create a new array `newIds` by fetching other ids from the backend.
I am using a recursive async function, and everything works fine, however since the function returns a promise, I am not sure how to convert it to a simple array of values because it's within a for loop. Any help and advice appreciated.

Comment: If you need to use the value returned by the `async` function, why not just `await` it? Am I misinterpreting the question?

Comment: I am but it still returns as a promise which needs to be resolved.

Comment: It doesn’t look like you’re `await`ing your call to your `async` function `checkForAssoc` in your top-level code. Can you point out where exactly you believe you’re `await`ing the result of this function?

Comment: At the end of the asynchronous function I'm doing `return await newIds`. I'm not sure how to return `checkForAssoc`, that's precisely the prime question.

Comment: `newIds` is an `Array`, though, not an asynchronous function. `await`ing it will have a net zero impact. Instead, use the `await` keyword with all your calls to `async` functions in which you need the return value before proceeding, i.e., `console.log(await checkForAssoc(thisId));` and `checkForAssoc(newDocToCheckArry[n]);`, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as though you're crawling the data, with the result for each input key possibly containing more keys to search.

If I've got this right, I think it makes sense to separate out the general crawling mechanism from the specifics of your code, configuring a crawler with functions that deal with your particular data.

This is an implementation of that idea, with a dummy version of `adminModel`:

```js
const crawl = (search, extract, convert, collect) => async (inits) => {
  const toCheck = new Set (inits)
  const found = new Map ()
  while (toCheck .size !== 0) {
    const first = toCheck .values () .next () .value
    const res = await search (first)
    found .set (first, convert (res))
    const newVals = extract (res)
    newVals .forEach ((val) => found .has (val) || toCheck .add (val))
    toCheck .delete (first)
  } 
  return collect (found)
}

const findLetters = crawl (
  (key) => adminModel .letterModel .findById (key),
  (x) => x .assocLetters, 
  (x) => null, 
  (m) => [... m .keys ()]
)

const combinedIds = ['a', 'e']

findLetters (combinedIds) 
  .then (letters => console .log ('Results:', letters))
  .catch (console .warn)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script>
// Dummy version of adminModel
const adminModel = {letterModel: {
  findById:  ((data) => (id) => console .log (`Getting ${id}`) || 
    new Promise ((res, rej) => setTimeout (() => res (data [id]), 250))
  )({  
    a: {value: '1', assocLetters: ['c', 'e']},
    b: {value: '2', assocLetters: ['c', 'd']},
    c: {value: '3', assocLetters: []},
    d: {value: '4', assocLetters: ['a', 'd', 'e']},
    e: {value: '5', assocLetters: ['b']},
    f: {value: '6', assocLetters: ['f', 'g']},
    g: {value: '7', assocLetters: []},
  })
}}
</script>
```

`crawl` here is a general-purpose data crawler.  It takes four parameters, and returns a function that takes an array of input keys (here, `combinedIds`) and returns a Promise.

The inputs are

- **`search`**, which takes a key and returns a promise for some result
- **`extract`**, which takes that result and chooses all keys it contains
- **`convert`**, which turns that result into something you want to save
- **`collect`**, which takes a Map from keys to the result of `convert` and returns your desired final output.

The function returned will take an array of keys and return a promise for the output of `convert`.

```hs
crawl :: ((a -> Promise b), (b -> [a]), (b -> c), ((Map a c) -> d)) -> [a] -> Promise d
```

In our case, we have

- **`search`**: `(key) => adminModel .letterModel .findById (key)`.  I don't know what this does, but I created a dummy version in the snippet above.  If that `findById` function doesn't reference `this`, you might be able to just refer to it directly, replacing `(key) => adminModel .letterModel .findById (key)` with `adminModel .letterModel .findById`
- **`extract`**: a function which takes the `assocLetters` property from its input
- **`convert`**: a dummy function since it seems we'll only need the keys
- **`collect`**: a function which extracts the keys from the `Map` supplied.

The heart of this, of course, is `crawl`.  It's a very lightweight data crawler.  It does its calls sequentially; if we wanted we can get more sophisticated and write one that bundles calls, it would be straightforward, and wouldn't alter the calling interface.  But that can wait.

The function returned by `crawl (search, extract, convert, collect)` takes an initial array of keys you want to use, and keeps two collections: those you still want to check, starting with the initial values (`toCheck`), and a map of ones searched to the result of the `convert` call (`found`).  So long as `toCheck` is not empty, we call `search` for its first key, take any new keys found by calling `extract` on the result and add them to `toCheck`, assign the result of `convert` to our `key` inside `found`, and removes the key from `toCheck`.  When the queue is empty we call `collect` on `found` and return the results.

One big advantage of this style is that the abstraction above is no harder -- and often easier -- to think about than a custom version for your specific case.  But now you can use it for many purposes -- say a web crawler -- and the code for your problem is as simple as this:

```js
const findLetters = crawl (
  (key) => adminModel .letterModel .findById (key),
  (x) => x .assocLetters, 
  (x) => null, 
  (m) => [... m .keys ()]
)

const combinedIds = ['a', 'e']

findLetters (combinedIds) 
  .then (letters => console .log ('Results:', letters))
  .catch (console .warn)
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you have misunderstood what `await` and `async` are. Imagine you have the following code:

```
async function something() {
  const v = await doRequest;
  const promise = v.body;
  return promise;
}
```

This is the exact same as:

```
function something() {
   const promise = doRequest().then(v => v.body);
   return promise;
}
```

Now from another async function you can call these with `await` and the result is whatever `v.body` is. however if you are not in a async function both of these returns a promise that you need to do a `then` with a function to be called WHEN it gets fulfilled like this:

```
something().then(vBody => console.log(vBody));
```

async and await are just tools so that one function can be written in a more eager way even if it only deals with promises.

Looking at your code `return await newIds` will return a promise right away that is fulfilled since it isn't a promise but an array. It will not wait for the array to be fully populated since you are not awaiting the recursive call or doing anything with the promise it returns. You are then doing `console.log` on the promise since all async functions return only promises. You also have bugs in your code where you should have `await`-ed for the recursive call to be returned or keep the promises you get in the loop and do a `Promise.all` to benefit from the IO wait to not be chained but be in parallel.

Comment: "*this is the exact same as*" - in your second snippet, the `promise` variable actually holds a promise, in the first it doesn't. You might want to remove that.

Comment: What would be a better way to write the code with the desired results, because whatever I've been doing either messes up the flow of the algorithm or returns results that are not needed.

Comment: @Bergi async functions always return promises so I choose the variables to match expectation.

Comment: @Sylwester But `v.body` is not a promise.

Comment: @Bergi  I have to mention that I actually wrote the promise version first and then rewrote it to async/await and kept the variables. I switched the order before saving. `something ` never really return `v.body` but a promise for it.

Comment: Sure, `something()` does return a promise, but the `promise` variable inside the first snippet is not a promise